Multiple agents in Node.js
Is it possible to use 2 agents when making an HTTP request in Node.js?
I need one agent to use my corporate proxy to access the internet, and I need one more to do the client authentication with a certificate to my endpoint.
This is my agent for the corporate proxy (A worth thing to mention is that my proxy uses the CONNECT method, so just passing the proxy parameter to the request will not work; Also I have an http proxy, but an https endpoint):
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';

const httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent('http://proxy-host:proxy-port');


This is my agent for passing the certificate:
import https from "https";

const pfxPath = "/path/to/my/pfx/file";
const passphrase = "myPassphrase";

const agent = new https.Agent({
  pfx: fs.readFileSync(pfxPath),
  passphrase,
});

Is there a way to use both agents, or somehow create one that will handle the work for both of them?
I have tried different libraries for making requests such as request, axios, https, etc. ChatGPT wasn't helpful, as well.

No. Thats not how it works. A agent is there to handle the underlaying network socket stuff. Why not pass the certficate stuff to the HttpsProxyAgent if supported or code a agent that does what you want?

Thank you. I followed your approach and created a new agent.

For everyone having a similar challenge in the future, you can take the agent from https-proxy-agent and after the socket to the proxy was successfully created, you can add the pfx, passphrase parameters.
